# How do I import a picture and put it on a pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, integer

I've been trying for a while now to make a destroyer type game using 'pygame' the main problem I have is importing a picture of a ship to use as the main player. And no  matter what I try, I always get the same error

> ```
> win.blit(win, char, (20, 20), (146, 149))
>    TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
> ```

And this is my code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
char = [pygame.image.load('char.png')]
run = True
while run:
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    win.blit(win, char, (20, 20), (146, 149))

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) is an instance method. Beside the instance of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit), the required parameter are the Surface which has to be `blit` onto the instance of `pygame.Surface` and the position.

Further more, `char` is a list of surfaces with on element.

> ```py
> char = [pygame.image.load('char.png')]
> ```

Change it to:

```py
char = pygame.image.load('char.png')
```

and `blit` the surface `char` on `win`:

```py
win.blit(char, (20, 20))
```

or

```py
pygame.Surface.blit(win, char, (20, 20))
```

Note, the `area` parameter (of `blit`) has to be a rectangle and represents a smaller portion of the source Surface to draw